# Coding PHP Code browser: is Bison/Flex a choice?

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I am planning to make Source code browser. Previously I wanted to use ctags but unfortunately, I found ctags is very limited as it cannot tell which class the method belongs to. I decided to check with another alternative. Reading the internet I have found many talking of using Bison/Flex. I have never used bison/flex so before I jumped in I wanted to know if it Bison/Flex is a right choice for my task. 
Thanks

Comment: Bison and flex (_not_ Adobe Flex!) are tools for creating compilers - are you sure that's what you are trying to do?

Comment: It just added the icon for Adobe flex which I didn't mean!

Comment: I have updated the question with a note!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that - doesn't answer my question, though... ;) Are you going to build a code browser, or are you going to build a code editor/compiler?

Comment: Codebrowser, a component of my already "in house" Editor. I want to be able to parse current file and populate symbols in codebrowser component (GUI tree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that flex and bison(or lex and yacc) are parsing solution.you can use this solution for both validating your code source and identifying by the way all symbols you may need in your in codebrowser component.

am currently developing a [ansi-c](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html) Grammar.validating the code and storing all typdefs structures.

This [document](http://foja.dcs.fmph.uniba.sk/kompilatory/docs/compiler.pdf) may help you, good luck.