# Flex/Bison PHP AST generation

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

This is basically second part of [my first Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583953/coding-php-code-browser-is-bison-flex-a-choice) which is about making source code browser. After reading tutorials I found that I need to parse PHP file and Build AST and from there I will have symbols I need. However, searching for days have brought nothing useful on how I can do that. Is there any tutorial or question already answered about building PHP AST?
Sorry if it is answered somewhere, my searches found nothing useful!

Answer (score 1):

You can look at how PHP does it: https://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/zend_language_parser.y.  Be advised though that PHP uses re2c instead of flex (grammar in ./zend_language_scanner.l).

Comment: I have already looked at the file and read both bison and flex manual but it is complicated! Is there a tutorial you know or may be explain a bit?

Comment: @Stefano A tutorial for flex and bison?  There are some introductions to their concepts in the manuals.  Putting together a complete "code browser" as you want to in the other question is on the other hand one of the most complex endeavours I can imagine.  I would start - after writing the scanner - to throw out all actions from zend_language_parser.y which should give you a validating parser and then inserting actions for "class", method definitions and the like.  But being a satisfied ctags customer in 95 % of all cases is probably much more productive.

Comment: Hi Tim, I went ctags route and it does not support PHP well, I cannot know to which class the member or method belongs. If you know how I'm not going this route. this is my last resort!

Comment: To know that, you would have to be able to say which class ```$a``` in ```$a->method ();``` belongs to.  You can't do that without running the script.  If you just want to jump to the definition of a method, visiting the file and then searching for the name seems easy enough for me (and can even be automated by macros & Co.).  For documentation, there are tools like doxygen that do a very good job.

Answer (score 1):

In 2017 there is **stable and powerful tool for that - [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser)**.

It allows TOKEN parsing and AST parsing of the PHP source code.

Here is [AST code generation example](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/blob/master/doc/4_Code_generation.markdown).

---

If you look for **C extension that would allow it**, check [nikic/ast](https://github.com/nikic/php-ast).

Comment: unfortunately I cannot see any documentation to use it outside PHP.

Comment: I recommend asking in issue there. I think @nikic will be able to help you much more than me.